# Find Rank of user on basis of points in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, ranking

I am using mongodb v4.2.1, with the following schemas

**first collection** : users

```
{
    _id: mongoId,
    name: String,
    phone: {type: String, unique: true},
    email: {type: String},
}
```

**second collection** : actions

```
{
    _id: mongoId,
    userId: String, // id from user collection
    actionType: Number,
    points: Number
}
```

The action collection keeps all user actions and some points given according to the action
**sample data: **

```
[
  { _id: 5dd8c0bdf950e60c143136bd,
    userId: '5da6e2cc6b1d4b838ec36999',
    points: 5,
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5dd8c0ba96bd1543c65ad72c,
    userId: '5da6e2cc6b1d4b838ec36988',
    points: 5
    __v: 0 },
  { _id: 5dd8c0b86cb0a156cf5cb684,
    userId: '5da6e2cc6b1d4b838ec36999',
    points: 5}
]
```

I have found the total points of each user by mongo aggregate like this:

```
action.aggregate([
        { $match: {createdAt: { $gt: "2019-12-01"}} },
        { "$group": { _id: "$userId", points: { $sum: "$points" } } },
        { "$sort": { points: -1 } },
        { "$limit" : limit },
        // { "$lookup" :
        //   { from: 'users', localField: 'userId', foreignField: '_id', as: 'users' }
        // }
    ]);
```

the above query gave me an array of top users with their points. I also get the rank of top users according to their position in the sorted result,

Now what I want is to get the rank of a particular user on basis of userId, I cannot find it from the sorted array as it can have a million users.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to:

1. Put the result after `$limit` into an array using `$group`
2. Then use `$unwind` with `includeArrayIndex` option to get the index
3. `$match` the wanted user
4. Finally use `$project`

```
const userId = '5da6e2cc6b1d4b838ec36988';

action.aggregate([
        { $match: {createdAt: { $gt: "2019-12-01"}} },
        { "$group": { 
            _id: "$userId", 
            points: { $sum: "$points" },
          } 
        },
        { "$sort": { points: -1 } },
        { "$limit" : limit },
        // 1
        {
          "$group": { 
            _id: "",
            topusers: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
          }
        },
        // 2
        { "$unwind": { path: "$topusers", includeArrayIndex: "rank" } },
        // 3
        { "$match": { "topusers._id": userId } }
        // 4
        { "$project": {
            _id: "$topusers._id",
            points: "$topusers.points",
            rank: 1,
          } 
        }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but like this i will get the points of the particular user, what i am looking is to get the rank of user i.e. the position of user in the sorted result.